Glovo Confirmation Email
glovo confirmation email
I would like to know if this is a form created by google or if it is possible to create it when creating an html email template, is it a some sort of setting inside of a email, is this some form of data validation, to check if this is spam mail...

Just look at the email's source and try to replicate it.

I found the answer on https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup , the problem while testing was that you cannot test with multiple mails, only with one where using https://www.google.com/script/start/ tool you need to write func to send yourself the mail with schema.org code inside of the html template of mail.
the appearance of the email after successful testing
